# How does one do a deepEqual assertion with should.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, should.js, deepequals

I've tried to make a deepEqual assertion with should.js (the latest version) and have not had any success.  I can get things to work with `equal` but not with `deepEqual`.  In fact I am seeing that there is no `deepEqual` method.

Here's what I've tried:

```
> require('should')
{...}
> > var x = Number(8)
undefined
> x.should.equal(8)
{ obj: 8 }
> x.should.equal(9)
AssertionError: expected 8 to equal 9
at ....
> x.should.deepEqual(8)
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'deepEqual'
```

Fair enough.  Now looking into `should`, I see it is a getter:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'should')
{ get: [Function],
  set: [Function],
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true }
```

Since it is a getter, how to I examine its keys?  This almost works:

```
> Object.keys(Object.prototype.should)
[ 'obj' ]
```

But then I see

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(should.obj)
{ value: undefined,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false }
```

So I'm rather stuck at this point. I would just like to see what things can follow `should`.

I *did* [read the docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/blob/master/Readme.md) and it says that `should.js` literally extends node's assert module, but node's assert does allow `deepEqual`.

```
> assert = require('assert')
> assert.deepEqual
[Function: deepEqual]
```

The should docs don't even mention `deepEqual` at all, which really has me confused.  To make things even more confusing, I *do* see a `deepEqual` when I enter `should` on the node REPL.  But it is buried in an `ok` element, as far as I can tell.

TL;DR: How do I call `assertEqual` or its equivalent from `should`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should (pun intended) use the `eql` method.

https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/#eql

```
({ foo: 'bar' }).should.eql({ foo: 'bar' })
```